# React Native / Redux - store is empty in middleware

Tags: react-native, redux, socket.io

I am creating a Redux middleware to use a single and global instance of Socket.IO in a React Native app. Everything works so far, except for one thing: when receiving data through socket events, I can't store it because I would need to dispatch an action to do so, which I can't do because I don't have access to the store.

According to this exemple https://gist.github.com/markerikson/3df1cf5abbac57820a20059287b4be58 which was quoted in Redux doc, and a bunch of other online examples, I should be able to access the store in the middleware, but the store is an empty object.

This is the middleware:

```js
const socketMiddleware = (store) => next => action => {

  // ...

  return next(action);
}

export default socketMiddleware;
```

And this is the creation of the store:

```js
export default function configureStore() {
    const middlewares = [
         thunkMiddleware.withExtraArgument({ api }),
         errorMiddleware,
         socketMiddleware,
         promiseMiddleware(),
         isDev() && logger,
    ].filter(Boolean);

    const store = createStore(
         persistedReducer,
         composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)),
    );

    const persistor = persistStore(store);

    return { store, persistor };
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: updated issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, but if the redux store system works like Vue's one, you should be able to import the store in the file where you need it, and access the store from the package you imported.

```js
import store from 'path/to/store';

// ...
store.dispatch('action', data) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I can't do that, since the middleware is initialized in the store. So if I call the store from the path it's defined in, it causes an infinite loop :/

Comment: Then instead of exporting the store directly, store it in a variable then export it after your Middleware, you'll then be able to access the store

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not the store being an empty object. I couldn't dispatch action because of a stupid mistake... The reducer I was trying to send data to was not part of the `combinedReducers()`, and so was never receiving action.